# debugging yacc YYDEBUG where is y.debug

Tags: debugging, yacc

I trying to debug a the yacc generated component for awk (awk.g.c) but when I define YYDEBUG it includes y.debug which I don't seem to have.

Where does y.debug come from?

Without it there are several references that are undefined.

I'm compiling the old 32v or V7 version of awk so I'm not sure if this is something that still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of yacc (in particular, the AT&T version, still available as part of Plan 9) generated an additional file with the suffix `.debug` containing debugging information, notably the table which translated symbol numbers back into names. Modern yacc-alikes just insert this information into the generated C file, on the grounds that the memory consumption is basically trivial these days.

The name table might not be generated if you don't request it, but the way you ask for it depends on the yacc version:

1. Most bison versions only generate the table if the [trace option is enabled](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing). (Posix mandates `-t` for this, but bison provides a host of alternatives and not all historical yaccs complied.)
2. As indicated above, some really old yaccs put the name table into `y.debug`. The AT&T implementation, as I mentioned above, always did this, but guarded the `#include` line with a preprocessor conditional on `YY_DEBUG`
3. However, the yacc implementation you pointed to in a comment, which uses the conditionally-included `y.debug` mechanism, only generates the `y.debug` file if you invoke it with the `-D` flag. So that's  what you need to do.

#### Background notes

I unearthed the information in point 3 from the V10 source linked in a comment. The download link is at the top of [this page](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V10); that wasn't immediately obvious from the link in the comment. (That's the complete source tarball, which is about 70MB. The individual files linked to by the link in the comment have been HTMLised, which makes them a pain to work with.) I could have saved myself some time by reading the release notes (called `yaccnews` rather than `CHANGES`). The last note in that file describes the implementation, and I include the paragraph here since it has all the details on how debugging works in this particular yacc version.

> 8/11/81
> Debugging changed.  If the parser starts with `%{#define YYDEBUG %}` and yacc is invoked as `yacc -D` (for Debugging), then the parser uses an external variable named yydebug to control debugging output. If `yydebug == 1`, the parser prints out the text of the reduction when it performs one.  If `yydebug == 2`, the parser also prints out the name of the token returned by each call to yylex, and if `yydebug == 3`, the parser also prints out the active items each time it changes state (this is uninteresting).

For what it's worth, it should be possible to generate a working, compilable parser using a modern yacc (such as bison or byacc). In the long run, that will probably be easier. (If you use bison and you require legacy yacc compatibility, you can use the `-y` flag. That flag is not supported by byacc, which claims to be legacy compatible regardless.)

Comment: I thought what you said had merit.  However I am (re-)generating the awk.g.c from awk.g.y on every occasion.  So I looked in the 32V/V7 version of yacc (that I'm using) but could not find any references to generating this file.  There are only a few yacc command line options and none are appropriate to debugging.

Comment: @WallyZ: i don't know what yacc you are using but if you indicate where I can see its source code, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: My source is from here : https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V10/cmd/yacc

Comment: Looking in that source, yacc contains a conditional #include to "y.debug" and so appears to need it rather than generate it.  Could the awk generate it?

Comment: The `y.debug` file is clearly generated by that yacc (conditional upon a command-line flag). The file is opened (conditional upon `Dflag`, i.e. `-D`) at y2.c:946; debugging information is written to it in the `defout` function in the same file at line 472. The conditional include which you saw is, I think, in the yacc parser template, `yaccpar`, which is not part of the yacc executable. I updated my answer.

Comment: All those line numbers correspond to the yacc source code you pointed me at. If that's not the version you're using, they might be inaccurate. If you're using a version prior to 1981, then you'll have to do the paleocomputing yourself :-) Good luck. I still think you're better off using a modern yacc, fwiw.

Comment: Confirmed added the -D switch the the make file and y.debug is indeed created.  If you add this as the answer I will accept!

Comment: @WalterZAMBOTTI: OK, I rewrote the answer, moving the information closer to the top.

Comment: @rici The reason I'm using this old version is I am (have) ported yacc, lex & awk from V10 to An old 1980's OS called OS9 from Microware.  64K (8 bit machine)  I was looking for a small footprint. In the end I managed to port them successfully without the DEBUG but much appreciated anyway.

Comment: @Walter: If you only have 64k bytes, you probably don't want the debugging tables anyway :-) I don't think they're helpful in running awk. Or even debugging it.

Comment: @rici I agree the tables probably wouldn't fit in the 64k space.  However I had the same source compiled on my Linux X86 system (cross-dev + native) and was doing the bulk of the debugging there.